# Get Associated Application of a Disabled / Stopped Service

Tags: powershell, service

### Problem

I am working with a PowerShell script to skim through a lists of known application services and, for any that are disabled, the script is expected to uninstall them. I have been researching how to get the application name/path of a target service, but failed to find anything suitable to my needs. I had tried working with Get-Service in hopes of that getting me what I need, but was not able to get the desired results.

### Question

How do I get the associated application of a target service that is currently stopped or disabled using PowerShell?

PS: Please understand that PowerShell is a requirement of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The running state of the service shouldn't really impact what information you get back. However `Get-Service` doesn't give you all of the configuration info for a Service, in particular the Path of the process being invoked.

To get that you can use `Get-WMIObject Win32_Service`. For example:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_service | Where {$_.name -eq 'wuauserv'} | Select *
```

This returns a `PathName` property amongst others that I think you will find useful.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't either; however, certain content seems to be non-existent which Get-Service. I'll give this a try and see what I can get. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Mark, this did exactly what I needed. I ended up hitting a new, related wall, but that can be saved for a new question. Thank you again for you support and pointing me in the right direction